# REGEX having difficulty filtering results

Tags: regex

So, I'm in an environment with half a thousand servers. I get backup alerts for every single one every single day. Makes it pretty hard to see which ones need attention. I've got this powershell script that parses my outlook and uses regex to find matches. Whenever an issue arises, I get something like this:

> ServerA    Error   1:04:34 AM  1:00:12 AM (+1) 0.0 B   0.0 B   0.0 B (1x)  0:00:00     Incremental copy was not processed during the copy interval

So, I see "Error" preceded by the server name.

Right now, I have:

```
(?m)^(?<servername>.+?)Error
```

Which grabs the items right before error, which is great. However, the alert emails also contain

> Created by bizznizz/nocgoblin at 4/30/2019 10:46 AM.   Error

At the very top, which I don't want.

EVEN WORSE, some of the input is also:

> 2019SRV-DB 90.2.0.10   Error   Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Where the server name is separated by an IP address.

I need to only grab A-Z, numerical, and hyphen characters between 2 and 15 characters, and strings that contain NO whitespace, and DOES NOT contain '.'

I think that should do what I want.

Right now I have three parts

The main expression:

```
(?m)^(?<servername>.+?)Error
```

Logic that SHOULD filter whitespaces

```
/^[^ ][\w\W ]*[^ ]/
```

And logic that SHOULD filter the characters I want

```
 /^[a-z][A-Z][0-9][-][^.]{2,15}$/
```

I'm just not sure how to put them together.

Here's an interactive example with my test input: https://regex101.com/r/hneDFw/3

Can someone show me how to do this, or source me some good material to figure how this? I'm a RegEx noob.

EDIT:

This question has been answered, but if anyone wants to see the powershell script I wrote to parse my outlook for alert emails, here ya go.

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

#------------
# Selects my Inbox, and then selects sub-folder under inbox. For my outlook, I have a subfolder called
# "Veeam Alerts" that I have an outlook rule put all of the account locked out alerts in
#------------
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)    
$subfolder = $inbox.Folders('Veeam Alerts')

#------------
#I'm using RegEx here because selecting the values is super dooper easy. 
#------------
$RE = [RegEx]'(?m)^(?<servername>\S*)(?:\s+\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})?\s+Error'

#------------
# For every email in my sub folder...
# (p.s., to check every email in "inbox", just replace $subfolder with $inbox)
#------------
$Data = ForEach ($item in $subfolder.items){

    #------------
    # Check to see if there's a match and if the recieved time is greater than the specified date, and if there is....
    #------------
    if ( ($item.body -match $RE) -and ($item.ReceivedTime -gt "7/01/2019" ) ) {
        #------------
        # Add it to $Data under "report"
        #------------
        Write-Host "Found: " $Matches.servername
        [PSCustomObject]@{
                report = $Matches.servername
        }
    }

}

#------------
# Now we sort through the data, count the occurence of each server, and export it to CSV.
#------------
$Data | Group-Object -Property report -NoElement | Sort-Object count | Export-CSv '.\backupfailed.csv' -NoTypeInformation

$confirmation = Read-Host "Report completed. File saved. When done reviewing data, type 'X' to close window"
if ($confirmation -eq 'x') {
    # proceed
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. Which parts of your test input u wanna match and which one not?

Comment: @Bambuk, just the server name

Comment: another one: `(?m)^([^\.\s]+)\s+(?:[0-9\.]+)?\s*(Error)` https://regex101.com/r/hneDFw/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?m)^(?<servername>\S*)(?:\s+\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})?\s+Error
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xkjap5/1).

Basically, the regex matches any 0+ non-whitespace chars at the start of a line capturing them in `servername` group, then consumes an optional IP address like substring and matches an `Error` word.

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `(?<servername>\S*)` - Group "servername": 0 or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\s+\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1+ whitespaces, 1 to 3 digits and then three occurrences of a dot followed with 1 to 3 digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `Error` - an `Error` substring.

Comment: You answered my question outright, it worked like a champ. I updated my powershell script and it grabed ALL the servers with errors, counted the amount of times they had an error, and dumped it out into a csv with absolutely no junk data in it.

But you went the extra step to break it down to teach me, and that's the most important thing. Thank you very much, I greatly appreciate you.